# How to display number of checkbox selected in datatable jquery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datatable, datatables

I have created a datatable using jquery. It has six columns, first column is checkbox while last column is textbox. Whenever user select checkbox, the count of selected checkbox should be displayed. Something like this:

[image]

Below is my jQuery code:

```
 $('#multiple-account-table').dataTable({
        "data": [
            {"accountNumber":"177723987389","name":"Account 1","alias":"dummy 1","dueDate":"10/19/2016","statementBalance":"34.60"},
            {"accountNumber":"3234344333","name":"Account 2","alias":"dummy 2","dueDate":"10/19/2015","statementBalance":"14.50"},
            {"accountNumber":"34343443443","name":"Account 3","alias":"dummy 3","dueDate":"10/19/2015","statementBalance":"15.50"},
            {"accountNumber":"43433442343","name":"dummy 4","alias":"dummy 4","dueDate":"10/19/2015","statementBalance":"15.50"},
            {"accountNumber":"13202553705","name":"dummy 5","alias":"dummy 5","dueDate":"09/19/2016","statementBalance":"100.50"}, 
            {"accountNumber":"13202553706","name":"dummy 6","alias":"dummy 6","dueDate":"12/19/2017","statementBalance":"18.50"},
            {"accountNumber":"13202553707","name":"dummy 7","alias":"dummy 7","dueDate":"01/01/2015","statementBalance":"105.50"},
            {"accountNumber":"13202553708","name":"dummy 8","alias":"dummy 8","dueDate":"10/19/2015","statementBalance":"15.50"},
            ],
        "dom": 'it',
        "pageLength": 8,
        "language": {
            "info": "",
            "emptyTable": "No records are available",
        },
        "columns": [
            {"data": null},
            {"data": "accountNumber"},
            {"data": "name"},
            {"data": "alias"},
            {"data": "dueDate"},
            {"data": "statementBalance"},
            {"data": null}

        ],
        "columnDefs": [
            {className: "pad-md-left-p-10 pad-top-bottom-p-10 white-active-bg mouse-link", "targets": [0,1,2,3,4,5,6]},
            {
                 'targets':   0,
                 'orderable': false,
                 'render': function(data, type, full, meta) {
                         return '<input type="checkbox" id="select-checkbox" name="payment-checkbox" class="multi-checkbox"/><label for="select-checkbox"></label>';
                 }
            },
            {
                'targets': 1,
                'render': function(data, type, full, meta) {
                        return  '<span id="pdf" class="stmt-identifier">'+data+'</span>';
                    }
             },
            {
                'targets': 4,
                "fnCreatedCell": function (nTd, sData, oData, iRow, iCol) {
                $(nTd).text(date);
              }
             },
            {
                'targets': 5,
                'orderable': false,
                "fnCreatedCell": function (nTd, sData, oData, iRow, iCol) {
                    $(nTd).html('$'+sData);
                }
             },
             {
                'targets': 6,
                "fnCreatedCell": function (nTd, sData, oData, iRow, iCol) {
                    $(nTd).html('<span class="dollar-font-xs">$<input type="number" id="payement-textbox" class="payment" value="" name="payment-textbox" placeholder="--"/></span>');

                }
             }
            ],
        "aaSorting": [[4, 'asc'], [5,'desc'],  [1,'asc'] ],
        "footerCallback": function ( row, data, start, end, display ) {
            var api = this.api(), data;

            // Remove the formatting to get integer data for summation
            var intVal = function ( i ) {
                return typeof i === 'string' ?
                    i.replace(/[\$,]/g, '')*1 :
                    typeof i === 'number' ?
                        i : 0;
            };
            // Total over all pages
            total = api
                .column( 5 )
                .data()
                .reduce( function (a, b) {
                    return intVal(a) + intVal(b);
                }, 0 );

            // Update footer
           $( api.column( 5 ).footer() ).html('<p class="total"><span>Total $' + total +'</span></p>');
        }

    }); //End of datatable function
```

Can you suggest how can I display number of checkbox selected by user?

Comment: try `$(':checkbox:checked').length`

Comment: But how to display that on my HTML page? See the image

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perform a checkbox count every time use checks a checkbox:

```js
var countChecked = function($table, checkboxClass) {
  if ($table) {
    // Find all elements with given class
    var chkAll = $table.find(checkboxClass);
    // Count checked checkboxes
    var checked = chkAll.filter(':checked').length;
    // Count total
    var total = chkAll.length;    
    // Return an object with total and checked values
    return {
      total: total,
      checked: checked
    }
  }
}

$(document).on('change', '.chk', function() {
  var result = countChecked($('#myTable'), '.chk');
  $('#checked').html(result.checked);
  $('#total').html(result.total);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
Checked: <span id="checked"></span> / Total: <span id="total"></span>
<table id="myTable">
  <tbody>
    <tr><td><input class="chk" type="checkbox" /></td><td>Text</td></tr>
    <tr><td><input class="chk" type="checkbox" /></td><td>Text</td></tr>
    <tr><td><input class="chk" type="checkbox" /></td><td>Text</td></tr>
    <tr><td><input class="chk" type="checkbox" /></td><td>Text</td></tr>
    <tr><td><input class="chk" type="checkbox" /></td><td>Text</td></tr>
    <tr><td><input class="chk" type="checkbox" /></td><td>Text</td></tr>
    <tr><td><input class="chk" type="checkbox" /></td><td>Text</td></tr>
    <tr><td><input class="chk" type="checkbox" /></td><td>Text</td></tr>
    <tr><td><input class="chk" type="checkbox" /></td><td>Text</td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```